# ITEXT : Write Non-English characters in PDF

Tags: spring, pdf, unicode, fonts, itext

Hi I'm creating PDFs using `itext (5.5.6)` in spring web application, from dynamic content which can be in multiple languages (33 languages are supported in my app).

Earlier I was using `"arialuni.ttf"` and evrything was working fine. I recently updated my app theme font to `"MyriadPro"` font. Since then, non-english characters are simply skipped from the PDF generated. For eg: Following string:-

> hello 怎么样 are you

is printed as:-

> hello  are you

**Q1.** I've checked some other answers which say that probably the new font doesnt suppport these languages. But if this is true, how is non-english content being rendered all over the application and the problem is occuring only in PDF generation?

**Q2.** Is there any way that I can write non-english content in PDF using this new font i.e `"MyriadPro"`? If not, is there any other font which supports all the languages? Is there any way by which I can use styling of my own font(`"MyriadPro"`) and the non-english character support of other font?

**EDIT:** 
Following is the screenshot of "Font" tab from "Document Properties" in Adobe PDF Viewer[image]

Comment: Take a look at the "Document Properties" of the PDF that you have generated. Go to the "Fonts" tab. What does it say? Do you see MyriadPro anywhere? Do you have a ttf or otf file for MyriadPro? (Note that it is **forbidden** to use the font files shipped with Adobe's Font Packs. How are you creating the `BaseFont` objects in iText?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Yes, under the fonts tab I can see MyriadPro-light & MyriadPro-regular fonts. I embedded both of them while creating this document. Yes, I've licensed ttf files for both these fonts.I'm creating BaseFont objects like this:- `FontFactory.register("path/to/MyriadPro.ttf", "lightFont"); font = FontFactory.getFont("lightFont", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, (float)9, Font.NORMAL, grey);`

Comment: That looks OK. I don't know what is going wrong.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Thanks for looking. I have updated my question and attached a screen shot of fonts tab. Could you please check if anything is wrong here? Also, could you please tell us about the feasibility of what we are trying to acheive ? We have searched through web and seen examples for multiple language support with `"arialuni.ttf"` font only

Comment: I have examples with many other fonts, but I don't have MyriadPro.

Comment: Ok.If possible, could you please provide us any example with other font? Or suggest any other font, which is working fine at your end.

Comment: The examples in the [Font tutorial](http://developers.itextpdf.com/tutorial/using-fonts-pdf-and-itext) all use FreeSans (see [examples](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/font-examples/examples-font-tutorial#15-f03_embedded.java)).

Answer (score 1):

PDF does not support UTF8 for text content on the page.  It can, however, support UTF16-BE if you need to stick to unmodified Unicode.  Such two-byte data, however, will require a two-byte font - and MyriadPro is not one of them - it's really only for the CJK fonts.

Reference: "https://forums.adobe.com/thread/641504"

Comment: How does this answer help the OP? What you are writing is totally unrelated to the question.

Comment: My answer gave clarification over this point :
 "Is there any way that I can write non-english content in PDF using this new font i.e "MyriadPro"? " 

 "MyriadPro" not being a "two-byte" font can not be supported under "UTF 16-BE" for non english text content on the "page".